# Facebook Messenger - undocumented features in Quick Replies

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Through building our chat bot I've come across a few undocumented "features" The latest one I've come across is to do with Quick Replies.

I made a typo and FB responded with the following error:

`Error: { message: '(#100) Param message[quick_replies][0][content_type] must be one of {LOCATION, POLL, TEXT, OPEN_NATIVE, STICKER, OPEN_APP, P2P_PAYMENT, TRANSPORTATION, CREATE_EVENT}'}`

Now there's a whole bunch of Quick Reply types that are not anywhere in the documentation - the Poll one in particular sounds very interesting.

Has anyone played with these?

cheers,
Paul